# Annual Alarm Mechanism with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to set up some kind of alarm mechanism with php + mysql. For example, Let's say that I have to pay some taxes different times of the year. These taxes began and expire in various years.

First I thought creating a record with it's payment date for that year seems handy.

```
+---+----+------------+
|aid| id |    date    |
+---+----+------------+
| 1 |  1 | 2010-01-31 |
| 2 |  1 | 2011-01-31 |
| 3 |  1 | 2012-01-31 |
| 4 |  1 | 2013-01-31 |
| 5 |  1 | 2014-01-31 |
| 6 |  2 | 2012-04-30 |
| 7 |  2 | 2013-04-30 |
| 8 |  2 | 2014-04-30 |
| 9 |  2 | 2015-04-30 |
| 10|  2 | 2016-04-30 |
| 11|  2 | 2017-04-30 |
| 12|  2 | 2018-04-30 |
+---+----+------------+
```

So I'm able to see my alarms a month or a week before with a query similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM alarms WHERE date <= x_time_after_current_date
```

However there will be millions of records in the long run. So I decided to change my table structure something like this.

```
+----+------------+------------+-------- -+
| id | first_date | begin_year | end_year |
+----+------------+------------+----------+
|  1 | 2010-01-31 | 2010       | 2023     |
|  2 | 2008-01-31 | 2008       | 2015     |
|  3 | 2012-01-31 | 2012       | 2015     |
|  4 | 2012-06-30 | 2012       | 2014     |
|  5 | 2005-04-30 | 2005       | 2015     |
|  6 | 2013-01-31 | 2012       | 2018     |
+----+------------+------------+----------+
```

But I'm not sure which is the best practice and how should I desing my query for the last example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, querying a table with millions of records is really not all that problematic as long as you have the table properly indexed, you have enough memory allocated to MySQL to keep the frequently referenced indexes in memory, and you properly utilize those indexes to query it.

I see nothing wrong with your first table structure as long as you have an index on `date`.

In your second example, you would likely not be able to use indexes effectively to even query the table as you would care only about the month and day portion of the `first_date` field for query purposes, meaning you would need to query on the corresponding data function, such that you wouldn't be able to use the index on the field.  This approach would also introduce some weired edge case logic when querying dates across year boundaries, that would lead to unnecessarily complex queries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In addition, these alarms is being recorded to the table dynamically after the event is created. Sometimes this takes a little time. May be, that lead me to the second way. Is there any better design to handle my needs? Or the first one is just fine?

Comment: @tuze I am not sure I follow what you mean by the alarms being recorded "dynamically".  Obviously if there is some asynchronous process that populates alarms into the database that could impact whether an alarm is available at the time of query, you may need to implement something to where you can't insert alarms with dates below a certain threshold relative to the current date to make sure you have the alarm information available when you need it.  I don't see how this would impact the table schema though.

Comment: I know I'm being boring. Process works as follows. Firstly an event is created by manually. Event type and starting and ending dates are selected from the form. So a second query inserts alarms to the db by the alarm type. A few if statement defines which time of the year alarm should be.

Comment: @tuze  I really don't see any reason that your first schema should need to change based on that workflow.